# Function $(2.2)^n$ -- what is it?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

The running time of an algorithms is $(2.2)^n$. I have to tell what is the maximum $n$ for reaching 1.000.000 steps.

What type of a function is $(2.2)^n$? How its output depends on the input $n$?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Best, 
Ina

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. $O(f(n))$ is defined only up to an arbitrary additive constant and up to a (positive) multiplicative constant. The big-$O$ notation is for asymptotic estimation, not for a finite number comparison, even 1 million steps. If an algorithm always takes exactly 1,000,000 steps no matter what $n$, then it is $O(1)$ and also $O(f(n))$ for ANY function $f(n)$.

Comment: Yeah, it is not enough to know that the runtime is $\mathcal{O}(2.2^n)$. If, however, you know that the algorithm has exactly runtime $2.2^n$ then it could be solved.

Answer (score 1):

$2.2^n$ is the same as $\frac{22^n}{100^n}$, this should tell you how it is calculated. We have the following inequality:

$2^n<2.2^n<3^n$. So it is exponential time, if your algorithm takes approximately $2.2^n$ operations then for an input of $25$ you need approximately $3\times 10^8$ operations, which is going to take a somewhere between half a second and half a minute. However, any input above $40$ will take more than a decade.